# Java in memory data storage thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, multiplayer

I'm making a real time multiplayer game server in Java. I'm storing all data for matches in memory in a HashMap with "match" objects. Each match object contains information about the game and game state for all players (anywhere from 2-5 in one match). The server will pass the same match object for each user's connection to the server.

What I'm a little concerned about is making this thread safe. Connections could be made to different threads in the server, all of which need to access the same match.

The problem with that is there would be a lot of variables/lists in the object, all of which would need to be synchronized. Some of them may need to be used to perform calculations that affect each other, meaning I would need nested synchronized blocks, which I don't want.

Is synchronized blocks for every variable in the match object my only solution, or can I do something else?

I know SQLite has an in memory mode, but the problem I found was this:

Quote from their website:

> SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many situations, this is not a problem. Writer queue up. Each application does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek a different solution

A few dozen milliseconds? That's a long time. Would that be fast enough, or is there another in memory database that would be suited for real time games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your architecture is off in this case. You want a set of data to be modified and updated by several threads at once, which might be possible, but is extremely difficult to get right and fast at the same time.

It would be much easier if you change the architecture like follows:

There is one thread that has exclusive access to a single match object. A thread could handle multiple match objects, but a single match object will only be handled/guarded by a single thread. Now if any external effect wants to change any values, it needs to make a "change request", but cannot change it immediately on it's own. And once the change has been implemented and the values updated, the thread guarding the match object will send out an update to the clients.

So lets say a player scores a goal, then the client thread calls a function

```
void clientScoredGoal(Client client) {
  actionQueue.put(new GoalScoredEvent(client));
}
```

Where `actionQueue` is i.E. a BlockingQueue.

The thread handling the match objects is listening on this queue via `actionQueue.take()` and reacts as soon as a new action has been found. It will then apply the change, updated internal values if neccessary, and then distributes an update package (a "change request" to clients if you want).

Also in general `synchronized` should be considered bad practice in Java. There are certain situations where it is a good way to handle synchronization, but in like 99% of all cases using features from the Concurrent package will be by far the better solution. Notice the complete lack of `synchronized` in the example code above, yet it is perfectly thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

the question is very generic. It is difficult to give specific advice.

> I'm making a real time multiplayer game server in Java. I'm storing all data for matches in memory in a HashMap with "match" objects.

- If you want to store "match" objects in a Map and then have multiple threads requesting/adding/removing objects from the map, then you have to use a "ConcurrentHashMap".

> What I'm a little concerned about is making this thread safe. Connections could be made to different threads in the server, all of which need to access the same match.

- The safest and easiest way to have multithreading is to make each "match" an immutable object, then there is no need to synchronize.
- If "match" information is mutable and accessed simultaneously by many threads, then you will have to synchronize. But in this case, the "mutable state" is contained within a "match", so only the class "match" will need to use synchronization.

> I would need nested synchronized blocks, which I don't want.

- I haven't ever seen the need to have nested synchronized blocks. perhaps you should refactor your solution before you try to make it thread safe.

> Is synchronized blocks for every variable in the match object my only solution, or can I do something else? I know SQLite has an in memory mode

If you have objects with mutable state that are accessed by multiple threads, then you need to make them thread safe. there is no other way (notice that I didn't say that "synchronized blocks" is the only option.  there are different ways to achieve thread safety).  Using an in memory database is not the solution to your thread safety problem.

The advantage of using an in memory database is in speeding up the access to information (as you don't have to access a regular database with information stored in an HDD), but with the penalty that now your application needs more RAM.
By the way, even faster than using an in memory database would be to keep all the information that you need within objects in your program (which has the same limitation of requiring more RAM).